# An alternative way to test primality of Mersenne numbers?

Tags: prime-numbers, primality-test

> **Theorem :**
>
> If [Mersenne number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_prime) can be uniquely written in the form : $x^2+3 \cdot y^2$ ,
>
> where $\gcd(x,y)=1$ and $x,y \geq 0$ then that number is a prime number .

Primality test for Mersenne numbers written in Maple code :

[image]

My question : Why this test is considered to be less practical than [Lucas-Lehmer primality test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%E2%80%93Lehmer_primality_test#The_test) ?

Comment: If you are going to loop $x$ from $1$ to $\sqrt{2^p-1}$, why not just check if $x$ is factor?

Comment: Your test is closely related to the so-called Fermat primality test, which does the same thing with $x^2+y^2$. The Fermat test can be pretty good at detecting nonprimes $n$ which can be expressed as $n=ab$ where $a$ and $b$ are close to each other. But its bad case running times are very large.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The number of iterations for your algorithm above is $\sqrt{N}$ where $N$ is the number to be tested, so it's no better than simple trial division (trying all the factors up to $\sqrt{N}$ to see if any of them are a divisor).  On the other hand, the number of iterations Lucas-Lehmer test is (approximately) $p$ where $N=2^p-1$ is the number to be tested, so it takes only $\log N$ iterations.

Comment: ah you answered as I was typing my answer :D